# AWS IAM manage MFA device with restriction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am using following policy for user to self manage MFA in AWS Console

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
            "Sid": "AllowViewAccountInfo",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy",
                "iam:GetAccountSummary",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnPasswords",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ChangePassword",
                "iam:GetUser"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnAccessKeys",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateAccessKey",
                "iam:DeleteAccessKey",
                "iam:ListAccessKeys",
                "iam:UpdateAccessKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnSigningCertificates",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeleteSigningCertificate",
                "iam:ListSigningCertificates",
                "iam:UpdateSigningCertificate",
                "iam:UploadSigningCertificate"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnSSHPublicKeys",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeleteSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:GetSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
                "iam:UpdateSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:UploadSSHPublicKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnGitCredentials",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceSpecificCredential",
                "iam:DeleteServiceSpecificCredential",
                "iam:ListServiceSpecificCredentials",
                "iam:ResetServiceSpecificCredential",
                "iam:UpdateServiceSpecificCredential"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnVirtualMFADevice",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:mfa/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowManageOwnUserMFA",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeactivateMFADevice",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAllExceptListedIfNoMFA",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": [
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:GetUser",
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
                "sts:GetSessionToken"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "BoolIfExists": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

With this policy, user is not able to change self password.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You probably don't want to do that. Allowing users to delete their MFA is needed if they need to change, like if they get a new phone. The policy restricts what the user can do if they don't have an MFA device.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: You've completely changed what you were asking for. When you say the user is not able to change self password, do you mean when they don't have MFA? It's not clear what you are asking for, and what the conditions are that are leading to your issue.